# Cable Equations and/or Calculations

Tags: power, power-electronics, cables

So, I'm on a placement as part of my final year of a Masters of Engineering Programme and the company have given me a task concerning a fault they may or may not have with one of their cables.

Basically, the cable in question is designed to carry a power load of 5kW less than what the building it is supplying power to has the ability to draw. I have a list of specifications for the cables but I'm more just looking for advice on relevant resources or equations for my problem rather than just being told the answer if thats possible? I suppose they want to know the circumstances in which their cable will/won't be able to handle the power supply of the building. I thought there would be pretty straight forward equations explaining this kind of engineering but I'm digging myself into a bit of a hole with it all.

How do I size a power cable for a building?

Comment: "Cable Equation" has a specific meaning, tied to Lord Kelvin's analysis for transatlantic communications.  It does not have to do with currents a cable is rated for.

Comment: In order to answer this question, we need to know the country and state/province in which this building is located.

Comment: @GlennW9IQ The building is located in the UK. Do I need to be more specific than that? Cheers.

Comment: @AliRobertson - start with BS 7671, the British wiring regs. This may lead you to further BS standards which are specifically about calculating "maximum demand", the amount of current your cable has to carry, and "cable selection", how to correctly size cables. (In Australia, I would use AS 3000 - our equivalent of BS 7671, and AS 3008, which is our cable selection standard.)